# Fastest pythonic way to produce i, j combinations

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to produce a `i,j` vector where every `i` is combined with every `j`, a simple version of the code would be this:

```
n = 5
m = 3

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        print str(i) + ',' + str(j)
```

Resulting:

```
0,0
0,1
0,2
1,0
1,1
1,2
2,0
2,1
2,2
3,0
3,1
3,2
4,0
4,1
4,2
```

However if `n` is `8e6` and `m` is `200` (like in my case) this loop nesting becomes very slow.

- Is there a numpy procedure to produce this combination in a C-like speed?
- Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want this output to be redirected? To a file, pipe, std?

Comment: `for i, j in itertools.product(xrange(n), xrange(m)):` is neater, and avoids building the whole list of numbers.

Comment: Also, check [cartesian product of large iterators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093364/cartesian-product-of-large-iterators-itertools)

Comment: Very slow? How fast are you expecting 1.6 billion `print` operations to complete?

Comment: Why do you want this utterly uninteresting, 1.6 billion line output? My best guess is that it's part of an attempt to brute-force a problem that really isn't amenable to brute force, and you should look for more sophisticated ways to solve the underlying task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` to produce cartesian product of items.

```
from itertools import product
list(product(xrange(5), xrange(3)))

[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2)]

In [13]: %timeit list(product(xrange(5), xrange(3)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 µs per loop
```

Your approach:-

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(3):
        print str(i) + ',' + str(j)

100000 loops, best of 3: 7.33 µs per loop
```

`Itertools.product` is even faster then `generator` function (considerable time deiffrence).

```
def solve():
    a = ((i,j) for i in xrange(5) for j in xrange(3))
    for i in a:
        print i

In [10]: %timeit solve()
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.25 µs per loop
```

Comment: What exactly were you comparing? Your first example doesn't have any `print` statements, your second example has string concatenation and one `print` per loop...

Comment: @TimPietzcker ohh! i used idle first that's why `print` statement, and i am just ttrying to see the diffrence between OP approach and use of `itertools`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator:

```
g = ((i,j) for i in xrange(5) for j in xrange(3))
for tup in g:
    print str(tup[0]) + ',' + str(tup[1])
```