# Create a list that contains all subsets from an upperbound (but where lst[i] ≤ upper bound[i])

Tags: python, algorithm, list, iterator, cartesian-product

I'm trying to build a function that:

- accepts as an argument a list of positive integers of length n and
- returns a list of all lists of length n consisting of non-negative integers with the following property:

  - for a list `lst` it holds that for all indices i, `lst[i] ≤ upper bound[i]`

For example, if the input list was `[1, 1, 2]`, then the output would be

```
[ [ 0 , 0 , 0 ] ,
[ 0 , 0 , 1 ] ,
[ 0 , 0 , 2 ] ,
[ 0 , 1 , 0 ] ,
[ 0 , 1 , 1 ] ,
[ 0 , 1 , 2 ] ,
[ 1 , 0 , 0 ] ,
[ 1 , 0 , 1 ] ,
[ 1 , 0 , 2 ] ,
[ 1 , 1 , 0 ] ,
[ 1 , 1 , 1 ] ,
[ 1 , 1 , 2 ] , ]
```

This is how far I've gotten:

```
def bounded_list(ub):
    f = len(ub) * [0]
    l = ub
    res = [f]

    while res[-1] != l:
        res += [lex_suc1(res[-1], ub)]

    return res


def lex_suc1(lst, ub):
    res = lst[:]

    i = len(res) - 1
    while res[i] == ub[i]:
        res[i] = 0
        i -= 1

    res[i] = ub[i]
    return res
```

which gives the output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 2], 
[0, 1, 0], 
[0, 1, 2], 
[1, 0, 0], 
[1, 0, 2], 
[1, 1, 0], 
[1, 1, 2]]
```

I'm not able to understand how to include the missing lists, any help woul be great.

Comment: Related: [Cartesian product of iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093364/cartesian-product-of-large-iterators-itertools)

Comment: You want a Cartesian product of individual `range`s. And [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) is an iterable which yields all the integers in the given range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an option:

```
from itertools import product

for lst in product(range(2), range(2), range(3)):
    print(lst)
```

note that your list `[1, 1, 2]` translates to `range(2), range(2), range(3)` here.

or more directly:

```
res = list(product(range(2), range(2), range(3)))
# [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), 
#  (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)]
```

or even:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2]
res = list(product(*(range(i+1) for i in lst)))
```

Comment: Can you generalize this to take one parameter `upperbounds`, which a list? That's what the question asked for. It's harder than just hardcoding one example list.

Comment: isn't that what the last part of my answer does? you pass `lst` containing the upper bounds as only parameter.

Comment: You just updated it with that. @olinix had previously posted that solution.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using an external package?

Comment: `itertools` is not an 'external package'. it is part of the standard library (i.e. part of every [acceptably recent] python interpreter).

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [itertools package](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertool-functions)
and [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

Then a solution is:

```
def f(upper_bounds):
    return list(itertools.product(*(range(ub+1) for ub in upper_bounds)))
```

Comment: Why won't the syntax `itertools.product(*range(ub+1) for ub in upper_bounds)` work, i.e. `itertools.product` won't itself accept subiterators? Why do we need to use `[...]` to force expansion of the subiterators into lists?

Comment: As far as I know the syntax you proposed is invalid because of the `*` in first position: on what should python apply the upacking? on `range()` or on the whole iterator?

Comment: I know that's a syntax error, I'm asking whether we can do that more elegantly than *\[splatting unpacking of all the subiterators? because as [Cartesian product of iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093364/cartesian-product-of-large-iterators-itertools) points out can blow out memory.

Comment: @smci instead of unpacking a list `*[...]` you can unpack a generator expression `*(...)`. although memory-wise this will not be much of an improvement here...

Comment: Ah ok, extra brackets needed. I suspect `*(...)` is cleaner and more memory efficient than `*[...]` Thanks for teaching me!

Comment: No, `itertools.product(*(range(ub+1) for ub in upper_bounds))`. Note that's `*(range ...)` not `*[range ...]`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: Ooops. Duh. Anyway yes I think `*(...)` is better than `*[...]`

Comment: Yeah ok, a geneator should be better, but if and only if the itertools method do not convert it to a list immediatly after that, and it seems it does according to the [definition here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product... anyway, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this.

```
from  itertools import product
li = [1, 1, 2]

#Generate a list of possible numbers to generate the output from the given list
iters = [list(range(item+1)) for item in li]
#[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]

#Generate all possible combinations of these lists
print(list(product(*iters)))
```

The output will then be.

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), 
(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), 
(1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)]
```